# Keyboard character is undefined even though there's no exotic character

Tags: errors, symbols, packages, characters, undefined

[image: Screenshot of my code]

What could be causing this error? I see no exotic characters in my line 17. I'm new to TeX, this is my first document. Tried googling this error, but most of the time it is obvious with some exotic character being put in the code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{admS}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\begin{document}
\udk{1.1}
\title[ПРИКЛАДНАЯ ДИСКРЕТНАЯ МАТЕМАТИКА]
        {ОБНАРУЖЕНИЕ ВРЕДОНОСНОГО ПРОГРАММНОГО ОБЕСПЕЧЕНИЯ С ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЕМ ИСКУССТВЕННОЙ НЕЙРОННОЙ СЕТИ НА ОСНОВЕ АДАПТИВНОЙ РЕЗОНАНСНОЙ ТЕОРИИ\protect\footnotemark}
        {ОБНАРУЖЕНИЕ ВРЕДОНОСНОГО ПРОГРАММНОГО ОБЕСПЕЧЕНИЯ С ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЕМ ИСКУССТВЕННОЙ НЕЙРОННОЙ СЕТИ НА ОСНОВЕ АДАПТИВНОЙ РЕЗОНАНСНОЙ ТЕОРИИ}
         {DETECTION OF MALICIOUS SOFTWARE USING ARTIFICIAL NEURAL NETWORK BASED ON ADAPTIVE RESONANCE THEORY}
\author{Д.\,Г. Буханов, В.\,М. Поляков, М.\,А. Редькина}
        {Буханов Д.\,Г., Поляков В.\,М., Редькина М.\,А.}
        {Bukhanov D.\,G., Polyakov V.\,M., Redkina M.\,A.}
        {D.\,G. Bukhanov, V.\,M. Polyakov, M.\,A. Redkina}
\organization{Белгородский государственный технологический университет, г. Белгород, Россия}
        {Belgorod state technology university, Belgorod, Russia}
\email{db.old.straygmail.com, p_v_mmail.ru, ritushhaagmail.com}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would help us more if you pasted your code instead of a screen shot.  Then we'd be able to copy and try it ourselves.  The `\maketitle` command is pulling information from the `\title`, `\author`, and possibly `\organization` commands, so those are the ones with problematic characters.  I'm not seeing how you're telling TeX what character set you're using, and it may be assuming ascii.  This can be adjusted with `\usepackage{inputenc}` (I think) or by using XeLaTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please cut and paste your code into your question; you can use the `{}` button to format it as code.  But a screenshot is needlessly difficult to work with.

Comment: I can't insert it with a {} button cause the chunk is too big. Also when I try to insert it as just a text then formatting from the interpreter doesn't save for some reason. Not sure what to do. I also use apparently a custom package admS, which is in my project directory and without it you'll need to include all sorts of different packages.

Comment: When I try to \usepackage{inputenc} there's an option clash on line 23 (which is \makeentitle on the screenshot)

Comment: You can certainly cut down the example to be just big enough to produce the error, can't you? This you should be able to paste.

Comment: Ok, I actually managed to fit it in.

Comment: Your document is probably utf8 encoded but somewhere in your package the is a call to inputenc with option cp1251. Try if it works if you remove this.

Comment: That is true, my document is in utf8 and the package has \RequirePackage[cp1251]{inputenc}. I tried deleting it or changing it to utf8, but then " Improper \hyphenation will be flushed." happens. I also tried including cp1251 package into the document but it results in an option clash on line 23. Changing my documents enconding to windows-1251 has no result.

Comment: Note that whatever encoding your original docuemnt is in, it is UTF-8 when posted on this site, so it is hard for us to reproduce encoding errors if they are due to non UTF-8 encodings.

Comment: I don't have the admS package. But todays standard encoding is utf8. So it would be better to adapt the package so that it works instead of reverting to some 8 bit encoding for your document.